# Classification Precision Optimization towards one class?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, classification, resampling

My dataset has two classes. The one of non-interested takes 90%, and the class of interest is about 10%.

I have already done the resampling, not only once, but a butch of balanced sets (e.g 10 sets). And do the majority vote to get the final prediction results. After compared many models, tree gives the best result. And I have already picked out the most important features based on importance scores.

The overall accuracy is not bad, 75%, but the precision towards the class I am interested is only 30%, which is not good. How to do the optimization towards the precision of the target class? I think the algorithms behind the ctree package in R is to do optimization towards the overall accuracy. I also tried the one-class classification, like svm, but not good. BTW, I used R and python both. But I do not find any relevant packages about my problem. Do I need to write my own tree algorithm which will optimize the precision of the class interested? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of models which give you ability to **weight** classes. This in general is better than just oversampling as it directly alternates the objective, not artificially tricks the model to overweight. If you use python, and like tree-based approach, Random Forest in scikit-learn has class-weight capabilities, simply overweight your minority class as long as the desired precision is not obtained.

Comment: But in general, does weighting classes do the same thing as the resampling? So I skip the oversampling step, directly build the model on my unbalanced dataset, and add the weights?

Comment: No, resampling in skewed and should not be used for models supporting weighting. They are similar but not the same. Undersampling is approximation of weighting, but only approximation. Oversampling in basic form also just roughly approximates (especially for some interative methods), and some oversamplers do more through introduction of artificial samples